# Passing result of std::bind to std::function "overloads"

Tags: c++, c++14, template-meta-programming, sfinae

I have problem similar to [Passing different lambdas to function template in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523248/passing-different-lambdas-to-function-template-in-c) but now with wrappers created by `std::bind` instead of lambdas.

I have two overloads of method `Add` that take different forms of `std::function`:

```
template<typename T>
struct Value
{
    T value;
};

template <typename T>
void Add(Value<T> &value, function<bool()> predicate)
{
}

template <typename T>
void Add(Value<T> &value, block_deduction<function<bool(const Value<T> &)>> predicate)
{
}
```

This now works fine with lambdas but fails with functors bound with `std::bind`:

```
struct Predicates
{
    bool Predicate0() { return true; }
    bool Predicate1(const Value<int> &) { return true; }
};

Predicates p;
Add(i, std::bind(&Predicates::Predicate0, &p));
```

fails with

> error C2668: 'Add': ambiguous call to overloaded function

and

```
Add(i, std::bind(&Predicates::Predicate1, &p, _1));
```

fails with static assert (Visual C++ 2015, Update 3):

> tuple index out of bounds

Is there a way to make it work both with lambdas and bound functors? I would think of using SFINAE to enable the individual overload based on `is_bindable_expression` and checking the argument type but I'm failing to put it together.

Comment: Both `std::bind(&Predicates::Predicate0, &p)()` and `std::bind(&Predicates::Predicate0, &p)(Value<int>{})` are valid. (In the latter case the argument `Value<int>{}` is ignored.) This is a feature of `std::bind`.

Comment: You're abusing overloading. The intersection of types which satisfy property "Instance of it can be called with this argument" or "Instance of it can be called with the other argument" is non-empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop using `std::bind`.  It is a mess of random features and quirks.

Todays quirk is that `std::bind` will accept an unlimited number of arguments and discard any extra ones.  Tomorrow you might run into the fact that passing `std::bind` result to `std::bind` does strange magic.

`std::bind` was ported over to `boost` at the same time lambdas where added to the language.  Lambdas solve almost every problem `bind` does in just as clear syntax and fails to have the myraid of quirks `bind` does, especially post C++14 when `auto` lambdas are available.  (Most C++11 compilers also supported `auto` lambda).

You can write functions so that one or the other is the preferred overload when they both apply.  But doing so adds a pile of noise to your interface, and in this case about the only reason why you'd want that preference is because `std::bind` is doing something stupid.

Engineering around a poorly designed bit of `std` library is not worth it.  Simply stop using that poorly designed bit of `std` library, or at point of use cast explicitly.

---

Failing that, do this:

```
template <class T, class F,
  std::enable_if_t<
    std::is_convertible<
      std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<F> const&(Value<T> const&)>,
      bool
    >{}, int
  > = 0
>
void Add(Value<T> &value, F&& f)
{
  // do pass f Value<T>
}
template <class T, class F,
  std::enable_if_t<
    !std::is_convertible<
      std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<F> const&(Value<T> const&)>,
      bool
    >{}
    && std::is_convertible<
      std::result_of_t<std::decay_t<F> const&()>,
      bool
    >{}, int
  > = 0
>
void Add(Value<T> &value, F&& f)
{
  // do not pass f Value<T>
}
```

where we throw some nasty SFINAE detection on which of the two overloads you want to use, and explicitly prefer one.

This is not worth it.

Comment: +1 for discouraging the use of `std::bind`, especially since we have C++14 lambdas and `std::bind` is actually poorer brother of that one from boost. I tried to think of a reason to prefer bind over lambdas, but the only semi-good one I came up with  was no-type-erasure, static-return-type for creating an event handler sequence, but that doesn't mean much if you can't spell that type.

Comment: @krzaq there are ODR issues with lambda-returning functions in inline header files in some cases.  I hope the C++ standard committee will deal with them, where they don't trigger (almost always completely innocuous) UB.

Comment: @Yakk I didn't know about issues with `std::bind`, I'll try to avoid it in the future. Nevertheless I tried your nasty SFINAE detection and it seems it doesn't work anyway. In VC++ I have troubles compiling it with the static assertion 'tuple index out of bounds' inside STL and with GCC while it compiles fine, the result is not what I would expect. It seems that both calls to `Add` with different bound methods end up calling the same overload. See http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/pcwxYAQcaoSxFQNi

Comment: @manison No version of MSVC fully supports C++11 yet; their biggest problem lies in SFINAE issues.  Asking a SO question on MSVC version-specific workarounds might get an answer, but sometimes there won't be.  That is what I expect from Gcc, as bind explicitly will take extra parameters and discard them.  That is what bind does.  When you call bind, that is what you are asking for it to do.  Passing the extra parameter is seemingly harmess, so that is what I had it do.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do what you want.

You can use `is_bind_expression` to check if your argument is a type produced by a call to `std::bind`, but there is no way to tell how many arguments the callable expects. As cpplearned mentioned in the comments, this is a feature of [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> If some of the arguments that are supplied in the call to `g()` are not
>   matched by any placeholders stored in `g`, the unused arguments are
>   evaluated and discarded.

That means that both overloads are equally valid.

---

If you don't mind sharing the same overload for all `bind` results, you can pass all the parameters and let them be discarded at will:

```
template <typename T>
void AddImpl(Value<T> &value, function<bool()> predicate, std::false_type)
{
    predicate();
}

template <typename T>
void AddImpl(Value<T> &value, block_deduction<function<bool(const Value<T> &)>> predicate, std::false_type)
{
    predicate(value);
}

template <typename T, typename U>
void AddImpl(Value<T>& value, U&& bind_expression, std::true_type)
{
    bind_expression(value);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
void Add(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    AddImpl(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u), std::is_bind_expression<std::decay_t<U>>{});
}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/oeJzcEriomypUucv)

But this is similar to using boolean parameters. In my opinion it'd be better for readability to dispatch on properly named tags:

```
template <typename T>
void AddImpl(Value<T> &value, function<bool()> predicate, tag::default_)
{
    predicate();
}

template <typename T>
void AddImpl(Value<T> &value, block_deduction<function<bool(const Value<T> &)>> predicate, tag::default_)
{
    predicate(value);
}

template <typename T, typename U>
void AddImpl(Value<T>& value, U&& bind_expression, tag::bind)
{
    bind_expression(value);
}

template<typename T, typename U>
void Add(T&& t, U&& u)
{
    AddImpl(std::forward<T>(t), std::forward<U>(u), tag::get_tag<std::decay_t<U>>{});
}
```

with tags defined as

```
namespace tag
{
struct default_{};
struct bind{};

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct get_tag : default_ {};

template<typename T>
struct get_tag<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_bind_expression<T>::value>> : bind {};

}
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/AuDFcNTcxllXTdQ6)

Comment: Then I can take advantage of this feature and have only one method `Add` with `function` taking the argument:

 template <typename T>
 void Add(Value<T> &value, block_deduction<function<bool(const Value<T> &)>> predicate);

and always call the `predicate` with the argument. The argument will be ignored if it doesn't match a placeholder in bound functor. However it breaks with lambdas. Is this good C++ solution? What would you suggest?

Comment: I don't know your use case, it might be correct, but it also might be overengineering. That being said, if you're okay with discarding the argument, I'll follow with an example that does this when I'm back home (2-3 hours)

Comment: @manison check the answer. Hopefully  you'll find this helpful.