# Why does std::function can implicit convert to a std::function which has more parameter？

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function, stdbind

I have the following：

```
void print_str(std::shared_ptr<std::string> str) {
    std::cout << str->c_str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto str = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello");
    std::function<void()> f = std::bind(print_str, str);

    f(); // correctly print: Hello

    return 0;
}
```

I think the type of `std::bind(print_str, str)` is `std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<std::string>)>`, but the code above is correctly running. Is there any trick in `std::bind`?

env: centos, gcc82

Comment: No, that's not the type of `std::bind(print_str, str)`. After all, the resulting function takes no parameters, the original function's sole parameter has been bound, so where would this second parameter would come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What std::bind does is correct. It uses the value you provided (str) for the call to print_str. So you don't need to specify it anymore and will always be replaced by the bound value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int sum(int value1, int value2) {
    return value1 + value2;
}

int main() {

    std::function<int(int, int)> f1 = std::bind(sum, std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<int(int)> f2 = std::bind(sum, 10, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<int()> f3 = std::bind(sum, 100, 200);
    std::function<int(int)> f4 = std::bind(sum, std::placeholders::_1, 200);

    int a = 1;
    int b = 2;

    std::cout << "the sum of " << a << " and " << b << " is: " << f1(a, b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the sum of " << 10 << " and " << b << " is: " << f2(b) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the sum of " << 100 << " and " << 200 << " is: " << f3() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "the sum of " << 200 << " and " << b << " is: " << f4(b) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
the sum of 1 and 2 is: 2
the sum of 10 and 2 is: 12
the sum of 100 and 200 is: 300
the sum of 200 and 2 is: 202
```

`f1` binds no values but placeholders and returns an `int(int, int)` like function

`f2` binds one value and one placeholder and returns an `int(int)` like function

`f3` binds two values and no placeholder and returns an `int()` like function

`f4` is like `f2` except that the place holder is now the first parameter instead of the second one.

Your code falls into the `f3` case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It is easily to understand. After I run your code, my another quest is, why `std::function<int(int,int)> f5 = std::bind(sum, 1, 2);` is compiled correctly? In other words, what is deduce type of `f` in `auto f = std::bind(sum, 1, 2);`?

Comment: stl does not specify the return type of std::bind. auto f has functor type and you can pass an arbitrary amount of parameters but at least the number of placeholders you specified by bind. The other parameters will just not be used

Comment: @Griyn That is a rather intersting observation. You should have asked for that instead of what you actually asked for ;-) It looks like `std::bind` has some unpredictable "features": https://stackoverflow.com/q/40547846/9883438

Comment: @sebrockm Thank you! It is also helpful to solve my confusion.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the type of `std::bind(print_str, str)` is `std::function<void(std::shared_ptr<std::string>)>`

No, the type of `std::bind(print_str, str)` is an unspecified functor type, something like

```
class binder
{
    void(*f)(std::shared_ptr<std::string>);
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> p;
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    void operator()(Args... ) { f(p); }
};
```

Note that this is callable with any arguments or none.

Answer (score 1):

What you are experiencing here is correct and is precisely doing what `std::bind` was designed for.

Simply speaking:
It turns a function taking `n` parameters into a function taking `m` parameters (where `n >= m`).
In your particular case, you give it a function taking one parameter and get back a function taking zero parameters. This new function will internally call `print_str` and always pass `str` as argument.

Side note:

Since there are lambdas in C++11, `std::bind` is sort of redundant.
What you are doing is exactly equivalent to this:

```
void print_str(std::shared_ptr<std::string> str) {
    std::cout << str->c_str() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto str = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello");
    std::function<void()> f = [=]() { print_str(str); };

    f(); // correctly print: Hello

    return 0;
}
```

This hopefully also helps understanding what `std::bind` does behind the scenes.